# Filter JS scripts which are storing cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have one HTML page where I have more than 200 `.js` scripts. Some of them are storing cookies in the user's browser.

Is there any way that I can filter a lists of scripts which are storing cookies in the browser and which aren't?

Answer (score 1):

Save the page with all the script files with your browser
File > save as
(check [here](https://superuser.com/questions/55040/save-a-single-web-page-with-background-images-with-wget/136335#136335) to do it with wget)

Then get in the js folder with a terminal and run

```
grep -l cookie *.js
```

You will get an idea of wich scripts are manipulating cookies (but not exclusively the ones writing cookies)